# Chrome dev tool show file name and line number instead of main.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

when I console log something,

I was pretty sure I got file name and line number before.

but now I can only see main.js and a number like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to change it back? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see a stacktrace with your logs, use `console.error()` or `console.warn()` instead of `console.log()`.

If you don't like the red or yellow color, you can use `console.log(new Error().stack)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I geuss you are looking for sourcemaps: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/source-maps/ .